# Angular HttpClient error handling requiring zone.run() to update UI?

Tags: angular, error-handling, httpclient

I am working on a simple Angular login dialog that uses HttpClient to post() to my backend API. I am strictly following the approach laid out in the [angular httpclient docs](https://angular.io/guide/http).

Everything is working fine, except in the case where an error occurs (I purposely turn off the backend API to generate a 504). Even in this case, all the error handling code gets executed exactly as I expect, but the problem is that the angular UI fails to update.

In the error handling code that's being correctly executed, I am updating a simple string variable in my component that binds to the dialog UI through standard interpolation; but the change never shows up in the UI.

Here's my service code that makes the HttpClient post call (note: I am using pipe() and catchError() and returning a new ErrorObservable as recommended in the docs):

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/timeout';
import { catchError} from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { ErrorObservable } from 'rxjs/observable/ErrorObservable';
// My models
import { SignupRequest } from '../models/signuprequest';
import { LoginRequest } from '../models/loginrequest';
import { LoginResponse } from '../models/loginresponse';
import { SignupResponse } from '../models/signupresponse';
import { ErrorResponse } from '../models/errorresponse';

@Injectable()
export class LoginService {

  private readonly loginUrl = 'http://localhost:4200/api/login';
  private readonly signupUrl = 'http://localhost:4200/api/signup';
  private readonly timeout = 20000;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  LoginUser(loginRequest: LoginRequest) {
       console.log('LoginService: login request ', loginRequest);
       return this.http.post<LoginResponse>(this.loginUrl, loginRequest, { observe: 'response' })
            .timeout(this.timeout)
            .pipe(catchError(this.HandleError));
  }

  private HandleError(error: HttpErrorResponse, caught: Observable<any>) {
        const er: ErrorResponse = {
          response: error,
          url: error.url ? error.url : '',
          status: error.status ? error.status : '',
          statusText: error.statusText ? error.statusText : '',
          message: error.message ? error.message : '',
          error: error.error ? error.error : ''
        };
        console.log('LoginService: error: ', er);
        return new ErrorObservable(er);
  }
}
```

And here is the component code that invokes the service call and subscribes to the resulting Observable:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Injectable, ApplicationRef, NgZone } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpResponse } from '@angular/common/http';

import { LoginService } from '../../services/login.service';
import { SignupRequest } from '../../models/signuprequest';
import { LoginRequest } from '../../models/loginrequest';
import { LoginResponse } from '../../models/loginresponse';
import { SignupResponse } from '../../models/signupresponse';
import { ErrorResponse } from '../../models/errorresponse';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['../../app.component.css']
})

export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
    ...

    constructor( private fb: FormBuilder, private loginService: LoginService ) {
        ...
    }

    public Login() {
      const loginRequest = this.ExtractLoginRequest();
      if (this.ValidLogin(loginRequest)) {
        console.log('LoginComponent: login request ', loginRequest);
        this.loginService.LoginUser(loginRequest).subscribe(
            this.HandleLoginResponse,
            // The line below should work fine based on everything I've read
            this.HandleError
            // But the UI will not update unless I use the zone.run() line below instead!? 
            // (error) => { this.zone.run( () => { this.HandleNetworkError(error); } ); }
      );
      console.log('finished the login request flow');
    }

    private HandleLoginResponse(httpResponse: HttpResponse<LoginResponse>) {
      const loginResponse: LoginResponse = httpResponse.body;
      if (!this.BackEndLoginError(loginResponse)) {
        console.log('LoginComponent: Storing access token in localstorage', loginResponse.token);
        window.localStorage.setItem('littlechatToken', loginResponse.token);
      }
    }

    private HandleError(errorResponse: ErrorResponse) {
      console.log('LoginComponent: handling error');
      // set the error text that is displayed on a div in the UI
      this.backendLoginErrorText = 'Network error: ' + errorResponse.message;
    }

}
```

And in the component template I'm interpolating to display the 'backendLoginErrorText' variable...

```
<!-- Login button and error text -->
<div class="centered">
  <button type="button" [disabled]="LoginDisabled()" name="login" (click)="Login()">Login</button>
  <div class="alert alert-danger" [hidden]="backendLoginErrorText.length === 0"> {{backendLoginErrorText}} </div>
</div>
```

As I've noted in the code comments in the component code, simply passing this.HandleError as the error-handling function to subscribe() does not work -- the UI never gets updated!  Note: all code is executed properly (i.e. the update is definitely happening, the change detection is just not working).

If I instead use this.zone.run(...) as noted above, the update happens just fine.

After much reading on SO and otherwise, I understand the basics of what's going on here -- something about the fact that the 504 error is happening after a few seconds asynchronously is somehow causing the error handling to be executed outside of Angular, necessitating the zone.run()?

I am just learning Angular, and a more experienced pal has told me "if you ever have to use zone.run() in a situation like this, you're doing something wrong". I find it really hard to believe such a simple scenario (basic login form with backend API and a post() call) -- using the suggested approach from the angular docs -- would require such a hacky-seeming thing....

What am I missing here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access the correct \`this\` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Comment: The problem is that the callbacks are set as references to class methods (`this.HandleLoginResponse` and `this.HandleError`), inside of which `this` is incorrect. If you use arrow functions instead, it should work. You could define the methods like this: `private HandleError = (...) => { ... }`. Or you could call them inside callbacks set with arrow functions. That is also the reason why the `zone.run` version works: the callbacks are arrow functions.

Comment: Appreciate the feedback, your comment nailed it.